# Google sheets - sum values in a key-value column pair for each key and display the results

Tags: google-sheets

Given:

```
  A   | B  |
______|____|
key1  | 3  |
______|____|
key2  | 5  |
______|____|
key3  | 7  |
______|____|
key2  | 9  |
______|____|
```

Get the output:

```
  D   | E  |
______|____|
key1  | 3  |
______|____|
key2  | 14 |
______|____|
key3  | 7  |
______|____|
```

I'm trying to use a combination of `unique` and `filter` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Using Query

The [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343) function is better suited to [SUM](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093669) the values in Column B grouped by the values in Column A.

**Syntax:   `QUERY(data, query, [headers])`**

```
=QUERY(A1:B5, "select A, SUM(B) group by A")
```

[image]

Below are some variations on the formula above.

```
   Exclude Blanks  
+----------------------------------------+
| =QUERY(A:B, "select A, SUM(B)          |
|        where A <> '' group by A")      |
+----------------------------------------+

   Custom Headings 
+----------------------------------------+
| =QUERY(A:B, "select A, SUM(B)          |
|        where A <> '' group by A        |
|        Label A 'Key', SUM(B) 'Total'") |
+----------------------------------------+

   No Headings 
+----------------------------------------+
| =QUERY(A:B, "select A, SUM(B)          |
|        where A <> '' group by A        |
|        Label A '', SUM(B) ''")         |
+----------------------------------------+
```

#### UNIQUE , SUMIF, ARRAYFORMULA

An alternative approach/formula uses the UNIQUE and SUMIF functions. Those functions are then wrapped in an [ARRAYFORMULA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275) so that one formula will populate all the necessary rows.

```
={ UNIQUE(A1:A4), 
   ARRAYFORMULA(SUMIF(A:A, UNIQUE(A1:A4), B:B)) }
```

[image]